# Appium support android unit testing or not?

Tags: android, unit-testing, appium-android

Appium support android unit testing or not. If **yes** then how to perform these tests and if **no** then which tool or framework is support Appium for unit testing. Or I have to use another framework or tool for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is No!.

It drives iOS, Android, and Windows apps using the WebDriver protocol as per [Appium site](http://appium.io/)

You can use JUnit for Unit Testing of Android Mobile Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Appium is not a unit testing framework. However , you can include your own unit testing in conjunction using Appium.

Depending on the language you are using , you can use TestNG or JUnit (for Java) , or unnitest (for Python) or others.